# Does it look like these boots are too long for my foot?

Tags: hiking, boots

I picked up a pair of these Danner DFAs (normally I wear a 9D) in 9EE. I went a little wide to prevent cramping I occasionally felt. Now my other shoes, including other pairs of Danners are all snug as 9D, width and length. This pair seems longer oddly enough. To the point of it. Are my toe's too far back? The line is where my big toe hits approximately. My heel does not lift when walking and they are snug everywhere except the toes (though if I try, I can push my foot forward), just to add.

[image]

Edit: Just to add. I wanted to try the normal width shoe as well. I put them side by side. The normal one is definitely more snug, but it's a very hard call. More pressure on the center of my foot. I want to clearly state these will be worn daily as well as some light day hikes (4-10 miles)

[image: Left is D, Right is EE]

Comment: I had exactly issue with my shoes. After a tough decision I exchanged them for a smaller size, which I found are perfect for my feet. You need to take the call I guess.

Comment: What happens when you walk on a slant downhill?  The store where I buy my boots has a carpeted slant board so you can simulate walking downhill.

Answer (score 8):

Hiking boots definitely must be bought a size larger than your everyday shoes.  The space in front of the toe is essentially a requirement.

1. Your feet swells considerably during a strenuous hike.  Do not underestimate this.
2. On a steep downhill you don't want your toes to push against the front of the boot, and essentially carrying your weight.  (Even so ensure that you trim your toenails before hiking)

There are techniques for dealing with your feet "sliding around" inside the boots.  Having the boot be a "perfect fit" is not the answer.  Use proper lacing technique, which differs for uphill and downhill treks, and which will go a long way to prevent blisters.

I use different boots for day hikes vs multi-day treks where I carry a heavy backpack, but even on day hikes you want space in front of your toes.

**So the short answer is:  That looks like a good fit.**

Comment: I don't agree with *Hiking boots definitely must be bought a size larger than your everyday shoes*.

Comment: The thing is they are tactical boots so they will be worn daily. Not just on rugged terrain. But good point.

Comment: I ware boots  one size bigger every day at work and they work great!

Answer (score 6):

The main issue with boot fit around the toe area is your toes pressing against the ends or the top. Typically you want the "toe box" to be quite roomy to allow free movement of your toes when your foot lifts and you apply pressure though your toes.

So the main problem most people have is their toes being too near the end. You're obviously not having that issue.

The main issues with having too much room in the toes is that you lose "feel". This is particularly an issue on more technical terrain. If you're climbing/scrambling on small holds then you're going to struggle a little the way they are. If you're not moving on technical ground and simply walking, and providing you're not tripping over the length, I don't think it's an issue.

Answer (score 4):

From your verbal description, it sounds like a perfect fit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/6073)

Comment: Yes it does, a perfect fit means it fits perfectly that would include length

Comment: Really? Even with where the toes are at that line?

Comment: @Escoce That comment was auto-generated by the website on my behalf which I'm not particularly fond of. :-) In my opinion, the answer is very short and does not bring much to that table. i.e. it doesn't elaborate on the question. It think it would fit better as a comment because of the lack of substance.

Comment: @Escoce Please add some more details :) the answer seems correct though

Comment: Just to clarify I'd imaging this has been [auto flagged because of the length of the answer](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/674/flagging-short-questions?cb=1). Hence the comments

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the boots being a little long. I wear a size 4-4 1/2 shoe normally but my boots -Mammut- are a 6, as the 5 nipped a little across the width.

I've surmised from information gathered from the internet and in the store that there are two important criteria. The foot should not slide forward during a downhill descent, as this would result in toe issues like losing toenails. This happened to me on a previous climb in my old boots, as my feet swelled too much. Also, the ankle should stay nicely in the heel bed, which can be achieved by lacing techniques. If you meet both of those, then they will be suitable. If you try these techniques at home and they fail then the boot will be too big.

I'm doing a trial on some longer boots right now at home for the same reason.